# Batch or PowerShell: How to get the last word from string?

Tags: string, batch-file, powershell, powershell-2.0, batch-processing

Here is my scenario:

I have a text file containing lot of lines. Each line is a path to a folder.

Example: 000.txt

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Blizzard Entertainment
```

I need to find a way to get the last child folder's name for each line and use it to create a folder link:

```
d:\>mklink /j office15 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
d:\>mklink /j acrobat "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat"
d:\>mklink /j "Blizzard Entertainment" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Blizzard Entertainment"
```

I have tried this:

```
$a="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
$a.Split()[-1]
```

With the result:

```
Office\Office15
```

I also tried:

```
$a.Split("`t",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[-1]
```

And the result is:

```
5
```

How do I get the last word of each line or word after last `\` by using Batch or PowerShell?

Comment: The variable should be get-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Batch - Take a look at the `for` command and string manipulation. You could do something like the following -

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (000.txt) do (
    set dir=%%a
    set dir=!dir: =/!
    set dir=!dir:\= !
    for %%b in (!dir!) do set ldir=%%b
    echo !ldir:/= !
    mklink /j "!ldir:/= !" "%%a"
)
```

This script loops through the text document (I've used 000.txt, could change this to a variable), each time setting the variable `dir` to the current line, which we are assuming is a directory path. It then prepares the string for processing by the for command (without the /f switch to loop through at each space character) by replacing all spaces with `/` (a character that a directory name could not contain) and all `\` characters with a space (so that there is now a space between each directory name). The for loop then sets the variable `ldir` to the last directory name.

Comment: This is great, also solved mklink with loop though all lines... nice .

Answer (score 7):

I assume those folders all already exist, if so there's a completely different way to consider:

```
Get-Content "000.txt" | Get-Item | foreach-object {
    cmd /c mklink /J $_.Name $_.FullName
}
```

So for each folder name you get the DirectoryInfo object associated with that folder. Then you can directly extract the last part of the path from the `Name` property.

This also has the advantage that you'll get an error if any of the target folders don't exist before you attempt to link to it.

Answer (score 6):

You were close, but forgot to specify the character you would like to split the string on, so it defaults to space:

```
 $a="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
 $a.Split('\')[-1]
```

Comment: one more quesion: how can I loop it to do each line in text file?

Comment: `get-content filepaths.txt | % { $_.Split('\')[-1] }`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another simple way to do it in batch

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (000.txt) do (
  mklink /j "%%~na" "%%~fa"
)
```

Comment: This solution is much better than mine - I for some reason had it in my head that `~n` only applied to file names, and not directories.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has a dedicated utility for splitting paths into their parent path (directory prefix) or leaf component (filename / directory name): [`Split-Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path).

`Split-Path -Leaf` returns the last path component only, which enables the following solution:

```
Get-Content 000.txt | ForEach-Object { cmd /c mklink /j (Split-Path -Leaf $_) $_ }
```

Note the need to use `cmd /c`, because `mklink` is a command internal to `cmd.exe`.